# How to set default startup applicationv on android tv 7.1.2

Tags: android-tv

Anyone who knows how you can change the default start up application on an Android tv box [H96 max RK3328]r.

I tried different autorun managers, but it doesn't work?

I want to use a visitors screen with videos that permanently loop.. Even when someone shut down everything? It would restart and automatically open the desired app.

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Used to be possible until the update to Android 7 by disabling the default home screen. That was blocked and AFAIK there's no way to do it without flashing your own version of Android on the device or rooting it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach is to delete your current launcher from STB, if you have a launcher on the startup. Check do you have settings button on your remote or any other way to change installed apps.

If you have adb with root permission.

To delete the Launcher do this steps:

```
adb connect <stb ip address>
adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
rm -rf /system/app/<current launcher name>
rm -rf /data/data/com.<developer>.<current launcher name>
```